# Resetting ESP8266 by software

Tags: esp8266, sming

I would like the ESP8266 WiFi module to reset itself after receiving a command via UART. Which code can one use to do that? Are there SDK functions like reset()?

I am using the SMING framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reset the device, you should call `System.restart()`, it is documented in [SystemClass](https://github.com/SmingHub/Sming/blob/master/Sming/SmingCore/Platform/System.h)

For instance the sample [Basic_rBoot](https://github.com/SmingHub/Sming/blob/master/samples/Basic_rBoot/app/application.cpp) call it.